# Office Web Apps views with Excel and Visio but not Word?

Tags: word, office-web-apps

I've upgraded to the new SP1 and July update for Office Web Apps and it's working fine with Excel and Visio, however I notice Word Documents are no longer working.

When I run `Get-SPWOPIBInding` everything looks the same:

```
Application     : Excel
Extension       : XLSX
ProgId          : 
Action          : view
IsDefaultAction : True
ServerName      : server.example.com
WopiZone        : internal-https

Application     : Word
Extension       : DOCX
ProgId          : 
Action          : view
IsDefaultAction : True
ServerName      : server.example.com
WopiZone        : internal-https
```

Interestingly I've only configured OWA to use HTTP (I've run `Set-SPWOPIZone -zone "internal-http"` via [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687(v=office.15).aspx)) to do that, but the above `WopiZone` still says "internal-https".

Anyway, any advice on why Word might not be loading in the browser and defaulting to downloading? I am over the VPN at this stage, so I'll try again at work from inside the network.

**UPDATE:**

I got the following error when searching for Word Documents and trying to preview them:

```
Exiting GetWOPITargetInternal Early - GenerateWacUrl failed to produce a URL/actionEntry for file XXX with extension 'DOCX'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicions were correct: the mismatch between `Get-SPWOPIZone` and the `WopiZone` of the `Get-SPWopiBinding` seemed to cause the error - everything needed to be `internal-http`.

I followed the article [here](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2014/01/office-web-app-ran-into-problem-opening.html) to remove and then recreate the bindings and Word started working (funny that Excel and Visio worked before but Word didn't!):

```
Resolution: Remove the link between the Sp farm and WCA 
PS> Remove-SPWOPIBinding –All:$true
Connect SP to the WOPI farm 
PS> $internalName = "wca.demo.dev"
PS> $internalZone = "internal-https"
PS> New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName $internalName –AllowHTTP 
PS> Set-SPWopiZone -zone $internalZone
```

Comment: Just for your attention: Microsoft only recommending running HTTP in test/development and HTTPS for Office Web Apps in production.

Comment: Yes and if you were using a `ExternalURL` you'd want SSL, however we're only using an internal url at this stage. So no need to manage certificates or take an unncessary performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you viewed Viso-Files through Office Web Apps Server?
There is no such functionality.
I guess it must have been Visio-Services within SharePoint Server.